# Rebase Relative Assets in Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, assets

I'm using [gulp-pretty-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-pretty-url) to keep page URLs clean in a project, such that a file `src/about.html` will be output as `app/about/index.html`. Some files end up in deeper structures though, like `src/series-460.html` to `app/series/460/index.html`. Of course, each of the HTML files references Javascript and CSS files, and they need to use relative paths.

How can I rebase relative asset paths in files as they're being run through a `gulp` task? Here's the file structure I'm working with:

```
project
├── app
│   ├── about
│   │   └──index.html
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── styles.css
│   │   └── js
│   │       └── scripts.js
│   └── index.html
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── styles.css
    │   └── js
    │       └── scripts.js
    ├── about.html
    └── index.html
```